# Input for an electric guitar

Tags: sound

I am new to dsp and I want to try making my own effects for electric guitar. I ordered a Line6 Tonecore developper kit but I won't have it before summer. Since I also want to try other embedded devices, I found the Rasberry Pi and there is a sound card available for it. But I am wondering, is the "normal" input on sound cards, like the Rasberry Pi and PC ones, are ok for a guitar signal? I got an impedance converter for guitar but is that enough? I know that the tonecore pedal has a built in low pass filter, but it could probably be programmed manually if I don't have one on my device.

Is there anything special that makes a guitar input different from a standard input?

Comment: I'll comment that I have used a mic input on a guitar, it worked with the PC I was useing, but it did not sound as nice as with an amp. So it depends on the level of quality your initial prototype is looking for.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm afraid this is not really a DSP question, even though it must be answered in order to get to some DSP later on ...

A guitar input is a high impedance ("Hi Z") input with an input impedance of typically \$500\, \text{k}\Omega\$ to \$1\,\text{M}\Omega\$. This is different from a microphone input or a line-input, both of which have significantly lower input impedances and they're also designed for  different voltage levels. If you have an impedance converter with an adjustable output voltage you should be OK.

Comment: I don't have a voltage converter but at least I know that a standard input is not designed for this. I will try something else. Thank you!

Comment: @transistor: Thanks for editing. Over at dsp.SE dollar signs (without slashes) are sufficient; don't know why.

Comment: I've had a couple of answers migrated _from_ this exchange to Arduino and DIY which don't support MathJAX at all. The admins didn't seem to be aware of this.